# Paperclip and Phusion Passenger NoHandlerError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rack, passenger

I followed this guide to get drag and drop file uploads through AJAX: http://dannemanne.com/posts/drag-n-drop_upload_that_works_with_ror_and_paperclip

Everything was working fine on my development environment with WebBrick but if I deploy to PhusionPassenger then I get:

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for #<PhusionPassenger::Utils::RewindableInput:0x000000041aef38 @io=#<PhusionPassen...
```

I'm using this in my controller:

```
before_filter :parse_raw_upload, :only => :bulk_submissions

def bulk_submissions
    ...
    @submission = Submission.create!(url: "", file: @raw_file, description: "Please edit this description", work_type: "other", date_completed: DateTime.now.to_date)  

    ...      
end

private
def parse_raw_upload

  if env['HTTP_X_FILE_UPLOAD'] == 'true'
     @raw_file = env['rack.input']
     @raw_file.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type }
     @raw_file.original_filename = env['HTTP_X_FILE_NAME']
     @raw_file.content_type = env['HTTP_X_MIME_TYPE']
  end
end
```

Looking at the request itself all the headers are set (X_MIME_TYPE, X_FILE_NAME) etc.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The example you're cribbing from expects the file stream to be a StringIO object, but Passenger is giving you a PhusionPassenger::Utils::RewindableInput object instead.

Fortunately, a RewindableInput is duckalike to StringIO for this case, so Paperclip's StringioAdapter can be used to wrap your upload stream.

Inside the if block in your parse_raw_upload, at the end, do:

```
if @raw_file.class.name == 'PhusionPassenger::Utils::RewindableInput'
  @raw_file = Paperclip::StringioAdapter.new(@raw_file)
end
```

Comment: I had I had a similar problem with Unicorn. Your answer helped me. Thanks. Link to problem with unicorn: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19359071/1530784