# Paperclip's error on a production server (unicorn)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, paperclip, unicorn

I use paperclip for upload images for post. For images there is a separate model, and posts has has_many relation. 
For uploading, http://github.com/Valums-File-Uploader/file-uploader is used. 
On local machine, all work fine (production and development mode).

Production server (ubuntu 12.04) uses unicorn + nginx. And when I'm trying to upload images,I'm getting:

```
Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for # 
                                               Unicorn::TeeInput:0x00000005cdd728 
                                               @len=619851, @chunked=false, 
                                               @socket=#<Kgio::Soc$
                                               app/admin/posts.rb:7:in block (2 levels)
                                               in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I helped this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15513492/1530784

I added

```
if @raw_file.class.name == 'Unicorn::TeeInput'
  @raw_file = Paperclip::StringioAdapter.new(@raw_file)
end
```

In method `parse_raw_upload`